# MySQL - Show questions not answered before

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a quiz that should show questions not answered before by the same user.
Therefore, a session is created when a user starts the quiz.

Here is the situation:

- There is a table "Questions"

  - This table contains all questions. There is a unique field QuestionId.
  - The questions always have a CategoryId from 1 to 5
- There is a table "Answers"

  - This table contains all answers given by users. The session id is stored in SessionId, the answered question id is stored in QuestionId.

I now am looking for a query that

- Fetches a question from Questions

  - Where Category Id = X
  - That has not been answered before (so the QuestionId should not be listed in Answers with the same SessionId)

My own trials and some Googling did not help. Hope somebody here can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    question 
where 
    categoryid = x and 
    not exists (
        select 
            '1' 
        from 
            answers 
        where 
            sessionid = y and 
            answers.questionid = question.questionid
    )
```

It will list all questions that don't have an answer from the user. You can put a "limit" on the results to get back only 1 row if that's what you need.